# Error while selecting MySQL raw with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

When I run following MySQL query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM credentials ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$result =mysql_fetch_row($result);
$username=$result["username"];
$password=$result["password"];
$gateway=$result["gateway"];
```

I get following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: username in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\switch\switch\index.php on line 78
>
> Notice: Undefined index: password in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\switch\switch\index.php on line 79
>
> Notice: Undefined index: gateway in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\switch\switch\index.php on line 80

Can someone please help me?

Comment: the semicolon is a fine way to end a statement (line 2 of your code)..

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchRow() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\switch\switch\index.php on line 77

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is on your line 78. But you should look at your semicolons.

```
$result = $result->fetchRow()
```

here is one missing. First you should look on your own and find a solution before writing here.

**Edit:**

$result is not an object. Use

```
$result = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\switch\switch\index.php on line 78

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\switch\switch\index.php on line 79

Notice: Undefined index: gateway in C:\xampp\htdocs\switch\switch\index.php on line 80

Comment: Then try mysql_fetch_assoc when you need a key.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM credentials ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$result = $result->fetchRow();
$username=$result["username"];
$password=$result["password"];
$gateway=$result["gateway"];
```

You missed a ; after $result = $result->fetchRow()

Answer (score 0):

Try mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_row

Fetch_row returns an Enumerated array eg $result[0] rather than result['password']

Answer (score 0):

IF there is an error with the query `mysql_query` returns a boolean .. so introduce a check for that :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM credentials ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$username=$result["username"];
$password=$result["password"];
$gateway=$result["gateway"];
```

Also note that `mysql_fetch_row` returns a numerical array .. to return an associative array use [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) (which returns both by default) or [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)